# how to exit try loop after code succeed?

Tags: python, for-loop, try-catch

my code below tries to execute a function x but because x takes time to build, i need to sleep until it is built then call it. So it usually takes me about 300s to build. When i run the code below, it will loop through the try loop about 3 times but print `0` every time it pass through the `except` code.

Is it right to put the `print x` (for when code succeeds and i break) outside the for loop like below or somewhere else? Also, how do i make `i` print the number of time it is trying instead of `0`?

```
    for i in range(0,10):
        while True:
            try:
                x = my_get_fuction
            except:
                print "error"
                print i
                time.sleep(100)
                continue
            break
    print x
```

Comment: This should work, but I think the approach is deeply flawed. Have you considered using an asynchronous model instead of the looping try/except?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: What do you expect it to print? continue will continue the while loop and skip the break, therefore only printing `0` until you hit the break statement.

Comment: @jxn, it's hard to give an example of how to do this asynchronously without more information. What exactly is my_get_function doing?

Comment: dont use a for loop, set `i = 0` and increment `i += 1` every time it hits the except block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop doesn't seem to be related to your design. Try this:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    try:
        x = my_get_fuction
    except:
        print "error"
        print i
        time.sleep(100)
        continue
    break
print x
```

This code will loop a maximum of 10 times, sleeping each time for 100s. If the assigned `x = my_get_function` doesn't complete by 1000s or so, then the loop gives up.